# Is it possible to select an element with jQuery using a variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to assign a value in jQuery to an `input` field with a variable name.

Basically I want to access inputs depending on the name of the input:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var inp = "input1";
        $("input[name='my<%inp%>']").val('hoera');
    });

</script>
```

But this does not work. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
var inp = "input1";
$("input[name='my"+inp+"']").val('hoera');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the string to build the selector:

```
var inputName = 'name';
$('input[name="' + inputName + '"]').val('hoera');
```

This is because the string is passed as a parameter to the jQuery function (that has an alias of `$`), so it doesn't really matter how the string is built by the time it gets passed in.

Answer (score 2):

```
var inp = "input1";
$("input[name='" + inp + "']").val('hoera');
```

Which is the same as

```
$("input[name='input1']").val('hoera');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var inp = "input1";
        $("input[name='my"+inp+"']").val('hoera');
    });

</script>
```